# Transparent Form background + Alpha channel, for moving windows in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, background, transparent

I'm trying to make a form with transparent background** (not "half visible" form, but form with "holes").

Now, I've succeeded in making a transparent background (without ALPHA channel) and one with alpha channel but one that doesn't refresh on movement of the form.

Here is the code I added to the form:

```
    protected override void OnPaintBackground ( PaintEventArgs e ) {
        Graphics gfx = e.Graphics;
        gfx.DrawImage(this.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
    }

    private void Form1_Paint ( object sender, PaintEventArgs e ) {
        Graphics gfx = e.Graphics;
        gfx.DrawImage(this.BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
    }
```

The problem here is that when I move the window with a timer (by changing its "left" property) the background stays the same (not refreshing the picture underneath the holes).

I'm certain that the Paint function is called, I've even added

```
        this.Invalidate();
        this.Update();
        this.Refresh();
        this.Show();
```

To the timer - just in case :) (it was a suggestion I read in one of the articles)

Basically the problem is that the background is not refreshed on movement.

I read about 30 articles about the subject before I came here, so I'll write what I'm trying to achieve in a better way, the form suppose to:

- Be with transparent background ("Holes")
- Support alpha channel ("half transparent pixels" on the edges)
- Stay transparent when I move the form around

Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: You cannot just leave parts of the window unpainted and hope that this will get you transparency.  The workaround is simple, set the TransparencyKey and the BackColor properties to Color.Fuchsia and get rid of your OnPaintBackground() override.  If that gives the bitmap a purple edge then you'll need to fix the bitmap and give it a hard edge.  If you need per-pixel alpha then you'd better switch to WPF.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response.

But I wanted to avoid the hard edge look.

is there a workaround without using WPF? (I'm afraid that it would be incompatible with XP)

what is the reason it isn't painting it?

if, for example, I change the visibility off and on it works again.
Thanks.